# Aliens stop a passenger plane in mid-air to hunt for other aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking to read up on an old book I read. It was a novel/book about an alien species stopping a Boeing plane to scan it for another alien species which was hiding on the plane.

One species was more technological, the other was more biological, I believe they were some kind of silvery metallic liquid that could change form and they infected other species. But I can't remember the name. It started with a passenger plane being stopped mid air, and is from the perspective of a human person. Some of the plot points involve the protagonist being chased by the hostile alien and taken to a facility to cure them.

Comment: An old book? About how old was it? Like 50, 60 years old?

Comment: I don't know, not that old I bet. Probably more like ten, twenty,

Comment: What is the specific cover?

Comment: Last I remember, it was a passenger plane in a lightning storm.

Comment: This seems a rather thin plot to fill an entire novel. It sounds like a short story. If it was a full length novel what else happened to fill the rest of the novel?

Comment: A short story might be the better word, I don't quite understand the difference between the two since I'm not an avid reader. But some of the plot points involve the protag being chased by the hostile alien and taken to a facility to cure them? I'm sorry it's been quite a while.

Comment: @JohnRennie If an entire movie can be built around snakes on a plane, why not a book about aliens on one?